# Copy Image between documents using OpenXml and C#

Tags: c#, openxml

I have two documents, I need to copy a picture from one document to the other. I can't use altChunks because I need to do further editing on the file.

I tried taking a clone of the sdtBlock that the image is in and appending that to the other document.

Like..

```
 sdtBlock = document2.Decendants<StdBlock>.First().Clone(); //Block with image and text etc...
 WordprocessingDocument oDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(document1, true);
 Body body = oDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
 body.InsertAfter(sdtBlock, body.Elements<Paragraph>().First()); //insert block into new doc
```

That works for everything except the image. The image appears as either a red X or the document shows as corrupt. If you take the image out this method works fine.

Looking on msdn I think its because I need to create a relationship for that image?

Can anyone show me how this is possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to copy the image part across, and add a rel pointing to it.  You need to make sure the relId in the paragraph matches the relId of the rel you added.

Have a look at DocumentBuilder in http://powertools.codeplex.com/ for how to do this.

Comment: Thanks. I though it would be simpler. I'll try this.